# How to get the sum of all the elements in a list using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
def sumAll(lis):
    return 0 if isEmpty(lis)== True\
    else head(lis)+sumAll(tail(lis))

def isEmpty(lis):
    return True if lis==0 else False

def head(lis):
    return lis[0]

def tail(lis):
    return lis[1:]

a=input()

print sumAll(a)
```

Can anyone tell me why it won't work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this with recursion?

Comment: yes, there is a function called `sum()` that you can just pass an iterable to.

Comment: `lis==0` is never going to be true, for starters.

Comment: As a side note, if you're trying to learn about recursion, you might want to try building a recursive list structure too: a `cons(hd, tl)` that returns `(hd, tl)`, and related `head`, `tail`, `make_list`, etc. functions. That way you'll get to learn more directly about the differences between folding/appending/etc. from left vs. right, tail sharing, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
return 0 if not lis else head(lis)+sumAll(tail(lis))
```

instead of:

```
return 0 if isEmpty(lis) else head(lis)+sumAll(tail(lis))
```

`isEmpty(lis)` is always `False` because:

```
>>> isEmpty([])
False
```

Why are you using recursion? I hope it's only for practicing recursions..

Tip: Always use debugger to really understand the flow of your program and to better catch bugs.

Comment: Or he could fix `isEmpty` to work, instead of leaving it broken and not using it.

Comment: @abarnert Indeed.. I think OP should be able now to do that.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Agreed; between your answer and Martijn's comments here and on another question, he should have no trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Using tail recursion:

```
def sumAll(lis, summed = 0):
    if not lis:
        return summed
    else:
        summed += lis[0]
        return sumAll(lis[1:],summed)

In [2]: sumAll([1,2,3])
Out[2]: 6

In [3]: sumAll([1,2,3,4,5])
Out[3]: 15
```

Python is not optimized for tail recursion, so there's no advantage  doing it in Python but in other languages in can be advantageous as it avoids creating excess stack frames because the function returns the result of the recursive call.
The function just calls itself until the condition is True.

In your code all the recursive calls have to complete before the final sum is calculated.
If you run  the code in [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) you will see the difference.

In your code change:

```
def isEmpty(lis):
    return True if not lis else False # change to "not lis", which is an empty list []
```

`lis` will never be `== 0`, to check for an empty list you can use `if not lis`.

```
def sum_all(lis):
    if isEmpty(lis): # same as if is_empty(lis) == True
        return 0
    else:
        return head(lis) + sum_all(tail(lis))

def is_empty(lis):
    return not lis

def head(lis):
    return lis[0]

def tail(lis):
    return lis[1:]
```

You can simplify your own code to:

```
def sum_all(lis):
    if not lis: # same as if is_empty(lis) == True
        return 0
    else:
        return lis[0] + sum_all(lis[1:])
```

Comment: Just `return not lis`; that is **already** a boolean. Never use `True if condition else False`; if `condition` doesn't already return a boolean, use `bool()` instead.

Comment: Rewriting his program to be tail-recursive without explanation probably isn't going to help him. You need to explain why you did it (and also maybe mention that it doesn't actually benefit anything in Python, but it's still worth learning about).

Comment: @abarnert, I have left the OP's program exactly as it was bar tidying it up and correcting the mistakes. Moreover I have explained why it did not work, actually used all the functions the OP was using and the code runs returning the correct result.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Adding a `summed = 0` parameter and reorganizing it to be tail recursive is a lot more than tidying it up and correcting the mistakes. It _is_ a useful thing to show the OP, but only if you explain how it's different and why you'd want to do things that way.

Comment: @abarnert, I was talking about the changes I made to the OP's code, I added an explanation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about reducing

```
def sum(container):
    if len(container) == 1: 
        return container[0]
    if not container: 
        return 0

    val = container.pop()
    container[0] += val

    return sum(container)
```

Comment: I think you mean `return container[0]`